# Salesforce, Impementing Single SIgn On from Metadata

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm trying to implements Single Sign On, on my ORG with a custom domain (customer.my.salesforce....)

I'd like to test the connectivity in a Sandbox environment (Developer Sandbox), but when i go to "Single Sign-On Setting" from Setup menu i cannot find the button "New From Metadata".

Why is this happening ?

In another ORG, of the same customer, we already did it in a Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it's a problem of API version. 
Seems that it's a new functionality available from Summer'15 ;)